# object and NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nspredicate

In my application i have a large table of around 12000 entries. I am displaying it on tableview. But the search bar is too slow while doing dynamic search. I have read that NSPredicate method is more permorfant then NSRange.

This is my old the code:

```
[self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects];
listContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dbAccess getAllBooks]];

for (Book *book in listContent)
{

    NSRange range = [book.textBook rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        [self.filteredListContent addObject:book];
    }
 }
```

My new code:

```
 [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects];
 listContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dbAccess getAllBooks]];

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@",searchText];

 [self.filteredListContent addObject:[listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

When i try to execute this code i received this error: "Can't do regex matching on object .'"

Comment: Why "SELF" and not "textBook" ? In other words you're not looking for entity but for attribute which contains "searchText"

Comment: I don't know if this is what's causing the error, but [self.filteredListContent addObject:[listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]]; should be self.filteredListContent = [listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Answer (score 2):

I would do something more like...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%k like[c] %@",propertyIAmLookingFor,searchText];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your book class a string?  If not then you cant use SELF like.  You need to substitute the name of the property you are comparing.